# Calculation of integral $\int \frac{wz}{w^2 + z^2}d\left(w^2 + z^2\right)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

If $w$  is a function of three independent variables $x, y$ and $z$, i.e. $w \equiv w(x,y,z) = x + \sqrt{x^2 - y^2 - z^2}$, how can one calculate the following integral?
$$\int \frac{wz}{w^2 + z^2}d\left(w^2 + z^2\right)$$

Comment: Well we know $d(w^2+z^2)=(2ww_x)dx+(2ww_y)dy+(2ww_z+2z)dz$. Using this we can write $$\int\frac{wz}{w^2+z^2}d(w^2+z^2)=\int\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$$ where $d\vec{r}=\big<dx,dy,dz\big>$ and $\vec{F}$ is the vector field $$\vec{F}(x,y,z)=\Bigg<\frac{2w^2zw_x}{w^2+z^2},\frac{2w^2zw_y}{w^2+z^2},\frac{2w^2zw_z+2wz^2}{w^2+z^2}\Bigg>$$

Comment: The integral you're searching for will exist only if $\vec{F}$ is conservative. Maybe you can establish some conditions on $w$ by imposing the condition $\vec{\nabla}\times F=\vec{0}$. I did notice that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\Bigg[2wz-z\arctan(w/z)\Bigg]=\frac{2w^2zw_x}{w^2+z^2}$$ $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}\Bigg[2wz-z\arctan(w/z)\Bigg]=\frac{2w^2zw_y}{w^2+z^2}$$ But I had no luck with the last component.

Comment: @MatthewHolder thanks. How will the function $ 2w\left[ z-w\arctan(z/w)\right]  $ hold up?

Comment: It doesn't hold up since $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Big[2wz-z\arctan(w/z)\Big]$ doesn't equal $\frac{2w^2zw_z+2wz^2}{w^2+z^2}$ if you assume $w$ is an arbitrary function of $x,y,$ and $z$. In fact, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Big[2wz-z\arctan(w/z)\Big]=2zw_z+2w+\frac{zw-z^2w_z}{w^2+z^2}-\arctan(w/z)$$ Can I ask from where you got this problem?

Comment: @MatthewHolder This integral came up while i was trying to calculate the entropy of a black hole. Here $w$ is the horizon radius and $x,y,z$ are the black hole parameters.

Can we say $wz$ is independent of $w^2 + z^2$ as along the circle $w^2 + z^2 = constant $ the value of $wz$ changes? In that case, the integral reduces to a simple logarithm.